# How to show message upon opening every new window in Tmux?

Tags: linux, tmux, fish, iterm2

I am using fish shell on Mac OS and I am using Tmux and iTerm2.
I want to show text with shortcut commands whenever I open a tmux window and new session.
Can someone advice, how to configure Tmux so that when ever I open a new session, it shows 2-3 lines containing the text I specify somewhere?
Regards

Comment: Unless you want this to happen *only* in `tmux`, this is purely a `fish` question.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `fish_greeting` variable to the message you would like, or define a function called `fish_greeting` that prints the message.

For example:

```
set -U fish_greeting "Hello, new session.
Type help for help."
```

or

```
function fish_greeting
   echo "Hello, new session."
   echo "Type help for help."
end
funcsave fish_greeting
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make it work by writing

```
echo "your message"
```

in the file~/.config/fish/config.fish

Find more info at https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html

Comment: Do not do this without adding `if status is-interactive; ...; end` around the `echo` block.